# Removing libjack0 removed a lot of packages

Tags: apt, package-management, sound, ubuntu-studio

I am new to Linux and I'm using Ubuntu Studio 16.04.

I just installed the libjack0 package and a message warned me that all of these packages would be removed:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ardour ardour3 gladish idjc jack-keyboard jack-rack jack-tools jackd jackd2
  jackd2-firewire jamin ladish laditools libjack-jackd2-0 libjack-jackd2-dev
  meterbridge python-laditools qjackctl qmidinet qtractor rakarrack slv2-jack
  ubuntustudio-controls zynjacku
```

I didn't see that message until I saw the "Uninstalling Ardour...". And that was the moment when I realized that I should not have done that. Hahaha..

My question is:

**If I install, one by one, all of those packages listed there. Will everything be like how it was before executing the command that made me remove all those packages?**

PS: Sorry for my english. I hope you can understand my question. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove `libjack0` (and the packages depending on it) and install the packages listed to be removed in your question then your Ubuntu installation will be *almost* like it was before you removed the latter. “Almost” because a manual installation will mark them as "manually installed" in Apt which means that they can no longer be auto-removed when no manually installed package depends on them.

The other difficulty here will be to convince Apt to remove `libjack0` without removing a bunch of other packages that depend on at least one of `libjack0` *or* `libjack-jackd2-0`:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-depends libjack0
sudo apt-get install -f ardour ardour3 gladish idjc jack-keyboard jack-rack jack-tools jackd jackd2 jackd2-firewire jamin ladish laditools libjack-jackd2-0 libjack-jackd2-dev meterbridge python-laditools qjackctl qmidinet qtractor rakarrack slv2-jack ubuntustudio-controls zynjacku
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Everything seems to be working fine =)

Answer (score 3):

Usually works this way, If you know exactly which packages had been removed, then everything should be ok after reinstalling them again, unless You also purged a configuration then your custom settings will be gone.

If OS informed you that all those packages will be removed, then either you really don't need them, or they have some kind of conflict with new app/package You want to install.

I would recommend, to run below command

```
sudo apt install -f
```

Above command will attempt to fix all broken packages if any. (`--fix-broken`)